# How to integrate vue js to server side rendering application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, keystonejs

We all know that vue js is for client side but I have an app which is server side rendering using keystone js but there is one part of the app that requires SPA and that is where i want to integrate vue js.

What i did is in the index.js I render the html

```
app.get('/page',function(req,res) {
        res.render('page.html');
      });
```

the html contains the following code but it vue does not work on doing this way.

Is this the right way to integrate vue js to a back-end rendered designe app?

Or i really need to generate whole vue project ? but only one page of my app that needs vue js (SPA) .

tHANK YOU. Help would be appreciated.

```
<html>
        <body>
          <div id="example">
            <p>{{ hello }}</p>
          </div>
          <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
          <script>
              new Vue({
                  el: '#example',
                  data: { hello: 'Hello World!' }
              })
          </script>
        </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "does not work"? Are you getting errors?. This generally works (although you should load the Vue library earlier).

Comment: I think vue doen't provide server side rendring directly please take a look into nuxtjs https://nuxtjs.org/ mentioned in https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html

Comment: @RK_oo7 the Vue part of posted code will be rendered on the client. The backend is just sending a static page.

Comment: You should be careful that whatever you are using to render your backend templates is not substituting your Vue template `{{ }}` variables. You should check that the source in the browser is what you are expecting.

Comment: @MarkMeyer , no error also , the message does not show which is the Hello World!

Comment: @MarkMeyer but it works when i open the html file directly to the browser

Comment: @RK_oo7 , so what is the best way of integrating the vue js app to a server side render designed app ?

Comment: @JhonCaylog when you look at the source of the code sent from the backend is it the same or has some variable substitution happened there as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201525/discussion-between-jhon-caylog-and-mark-meyer).

Comment: I just actually render the page from the backend, thats it

Comment: @MarkMeyer , yeah it works when i directly open it on the browser but it does not work when i render the page from backend

Comment: @MarkMeyer , , any idea ? what would help?

Comment: No, doesn’t make sense to me. If it’s the same source I would expect the same result.

Comment: I tried even adding<script>
              new Vue({
                  el: '#example',
                  data: { hello: 'Hello World!' }
              })

              console.log("fff")
          </script>

and the console logs show on the browser

Comment: @MarkMeyer is this the only best solution on integrating vue to my server side rendered app ? or is there a better way?

Comment: i found the solution using {% verbatim %}

Comment: it has something to do with the nunjucks